# Why PayPal Request can’t be processed?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, recurring-billing

I’m trying to test recurring payment in my paypal sandbox account. I followed this link https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/

I have summarized the steps what I follow

Step 1: Get PayPal Token – Completed

Step 2: Redirect customer to PayPal with Token
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=xxxxxxxx

After I send the request, paypal show the following page

[image]

After I entered the sandbox buyer account details, paypal display error message like **“Currently, we unfortunately can not process your request. Return to Logical IT Solution GmbH and select another option.”**

I have tried So many times, PayPal show this message only.
How can I implement recurring payment for my sandbox account without error?

Answer (score 0):

You test German paypal account? If yes than Paypal recurring payments does not work with German accounts or at least not with all of them. This is some legal problem and that's why they disabled it.

Probably German law refuse to store recurring payments data on foreign servers.